# Is there a simple way to install every Ansible azure-mgmt-* Python package?

Tags: python, azure, ansible

Every time I run

```
ansible localhost -m azure.azcollection.azure_rm_resourcegroup -a "name=resourceGroup location=eastus"
```

I get an error regarding a missing `azure.mgmt.*` module, e.g.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt.sql'
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on rocky8Ansible's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
```

I'll install the module, re-run the command, and get another error for a different module. Rinse, repeat.

I've installed the `azure.azcollection` which provides the `az_rm_*` modules, but not the `azure-mgmt-*` modules.

Now that `pip` no longer supports the `search` option I can't do a search and loop through the results to install everything. Every `requirements.txt` file I've found (even the most recent from the `ansible-collections/azure` repo) pins to older versions.

I've also tried `pypisearch`, `pip_search`, and `poetry` but the output hasn't been useful. The former outputs a table of results and the latter two don't even find any of the `azure-mgmt-*` modules.

I did parse the `pip_search` output through `awk`, but the command only returns the first page of multiple pages of results leaving me with still many packages to install.

Is there a simpler way to do this that doesn't require manually updating the versions in a `requirements-azure.txt` file or iterating through each missing module?

Comment: Maybe a good starting point for research [Microsoft Azure SDK for Python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt/) and [Azure SDK Releases](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html).

Comment: Why would you want to install other python modules versions than the ones referenced in the requirement file distributed with the collection version you installed? The [official documentation](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/azure/azcollection/docs/) is quite clear: `pip3 install -r ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt`

Comment: @Zeitounator When I installed from the `requirements-azure.txt` file, already installed versions would be removed. This would leave other modules with broken dependencies.

Comment: And this why it is strongly advised to install ansible and its collections in a virtualenv as this is clearly recalled in the above documentation.